# Need help with understanding sentence

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

What does ***accessing schedules*** mean?

> Digital technologies *provide access* to schedule for employees.

or

> That digital technologies *have* access to schedule.

[Source](http://www.fastcasual.com/articles/back-to-the-future-6-innovative-technologies-saving-restaurants-money-and-changing-the-industry/):

> Some examples include tracking food costs, ***accessing schedules*** and
>   scheduling labor and using barcode scanners to check inventory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In context, *accessing schedules* is of the form [verb noun], that is, that one of the "advantages these cloud-based systems can provide" is to be able to access schedules.

> provide access ... or ... have access

Of the two, providing access is primary. This, of course, implies that these systems *have access* to the same schedules as well.

Answer (score 2):

The verb [***access***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/access) in the sentence was used to mean the following:

> ***Obtain or retrieve*** (computer data or a file): *information can be
>   accessed from several files and displayed at the same time*

The paragraph in the link mainly explains about advantages (efficiency) of using *Digital workforce management and energy analytics*.

If you could ***retrieve data*** on schedules of transporting (trucking) your inventory (meat, vegetables and ingredients, etc.), it would be more efficient in terms of managing your restaurant and workforce.

Answer (score 1):

If you drill down to the **original article** that was cited within the article you linked to, it will make more sense:

http://www.pizzamarketplace.com/articles/millennial-workforce-driving-digital-workforce-management-solutions/

Interactive scheduling shows both managers and employees who is expected to work when. The cartoon at the top of the page is useful in understanding this concept. Both articles are full of **"digital business" jargon** that would be difficult to understand for a non-native speaker of English.